# Проблема с добавлением материала joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

Доброго времени суток. Есть сайт на `joomla 1.5`, висит он. Давно его не юзал, сейчас понадобилось добавить материал. Позавчера все было нормально, вчера возникла такая проблема: в общем нажимаю кнопку сохранить или изменить и ничего не происходит. Погуглил, решения ясного не нашел, все попробовал, но проблема осталась.
Вот такие ошибки js (с разными редакторами-разные):
**FCK:**

```
unterminated string literal
Ошибка: FCKConfig is not defined
Источник: http:///plugins/editors/fckeditor/fckconfig.js?ver=2641
Строка: 27
Ошибка: FCKBrowserInfo is not defined
Источник: http:///plugins/editors/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=text&Toolbar=Advanced
Строка: 125
Ошибка: FCKConfig_LoadPageConfig is not defined
Источник: http:///plugins/editors/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=text&Toolbar=Advanced
Строка: 164
Ошибка: InitializeAPI is not defined
Источник: http://badminton-minsk.com/plugins/editors/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=text&Toolbar=Advanced
Строка: 210
```

С **tinyMCE**

```
untermined string literal
Ошибка: tinyMCE is not defined
Источник: http:///administrator/index.php?option=com_content&sectionid=-1&task=edit&cid[]=31
Строка: 161
Ошибка: tinyMCE is not defined
Источник: http:///administrator/index.php?option=com_content&sectionid=-1&task=edit&cid[]=31
Строка: 384
```

Нет соображений, в яваскрипте слаб, подскажите чего, пожалуйста. 
PS: не понял как с новыми строками сделать, все в кучу:(

Comment: Накатите новую версию Джумлы поверх и будет вам счастье.

Comment: А больше никаких вариантов? Просто не очень хочется переставлять, слишком много проблем может вылезти, мне-то не критично, только бы материалы добавлялись